# BI development in Microsoft BI

Tags: ssis, ssas, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I need to learn how to create a dimensional modelling for an organisation that do not has a BI tool and BI model.

Where can I learn more about BI development that should be used in a company?

IT's development and NOT maintainence I need to learn. The tool I'm using is Microsoft BI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BI Development is a big subject to learn and will take a lot of time understand all the concepts, I would suggest this book as place to start your journey of discovery: The Microsoft Data Warehouse Toolkit: With SQL Server 2008 R2 and the Microsoft Business Intelligence Toolset by Joy Mundy
Permalink: [http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0470640383](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470640383)